# How to generate a certificate signature on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, digital-signature

If I had a private certificate file and a string on the iPhone, how do I use them to generate a signed string that can be verified by a server with the matching public key? What library should I use on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html) on Apple's website. You can import the PKCS #12–formatted blob with [SecPKCS12Import](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecPKCS12Import) and sign the data with [SecKeyRawSign](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyRawSign).